# How can I get the nth character of a string?

Tags: c, string, memory, char

I have a string,

```
char* str = "HELLO"
```

If I wanted to get just the `E` from that how would I do that?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You would do:

```
char c = str[1];
```

Or even:

```
char c = "Hello"[1];
```

edit: updated to find the "E".

Comment: Well, nuts, I misread. I was going for the "O" instead. Still the answer still applies.

Comment: @Aspyn Just for your information, accessing a string like this is fine, but trying to modify it is illegal in `C` (You can't do `str[0] = "J"`, where `str` points to a string literal).

Answer (score 30):

```
char* str = "HELLO";
char c = str[1];
```

Keep in mind that arrays and strings in C begin indexing at 0 rather than 1, so "H" is `str[0]`, "E" is `str[1]`, the first "L" is `str[2]` and so on.

Comment: What if the encoding is utf8 and not all characters are ascii?

Answer (score 5):

Array notation and pointer arithmetic can be used interchangeably in C/C++ (this is not true for ALL the cases but by the time you get there, you will find the cases yourself). So although `str` is a pointer, you can use it as if it were an array like so:

```
char char_E = str[1];
char char_L1 = str[2];
char char_O = str[4];
```

...and so on. What you could also do is "add" 1 to the value of the pointer to a character `str` which will then point to the second character in the string. Then you can simply do:

```
str = str + 1; // makes it point to 'E' now
char myChar =  *str;
```

I hope this helps.