# Whats the cout << i << " \n"[ i == n ] term doing?

Tags: c++, loops, cout

In this statement

```
for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    cout << i << " \n"[ i == n ];
}
```

what is the last term in `cout` statement `[i==n]` doing?
This loop prints space separate numbers I guess.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get the nth character of a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8454228/how-can-i-get-the-nth-character-of-a-string)

Comment: @underscore_d: Definitely not. Note the unusual expression in `[ i==n ]` .

Comment: and through standard boolean evaluation, `i == n` becomes `0` or `1`. So, once someone learns what `"foo"[bar]` does, `"foo"[i == n]` seems trivial to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a silly way to index either the character `' '` or the character `'\n'`. This does the same idea and prints "Hello World":

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
                std::cout << "Hello World"[i];
        return 0;
}
```

`i == n` is either going to be `true` or `false`. When cast to an integer for indexing using `[i == n]` you get either the first or second element

Comment: Realy right use of the silly qualifier (It should be standardized)!

Comment: Wonderful! Only, I would swap the arguments to `[]` for added quality. `i["Hello World"]`. ;-)

Answer (score 15):

It is an obtuse way of writing:

```
(i == n ? '\n' : ' ')
```

That is, when `i == n`, a newline is printed, otherwise a space is printed.

The idea is to separate the numbers by spaces, and to put a newline after all the numbers have been printed.

Comment: Never seen this before!