# How can I re-iterate from the beginning of a string after iterating through it?

Tags: python, string

I am sorry, but I couldn't think of any other way to put this question. I find many coding questions regarding this topic, where after iterating through a `string`, I have to reiterate through the beginning of the `string`(where *new index=index of last element + 1*).

Suppose there is a string:

```
S='abcdefgh'
```

I want to iterate through each and every element, where the indexes are like this:

```
a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h

0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7

8  9  10 11 12 13 14 15.... and so on.
```

I am a noob programmer so please excuse me for these silly questions. So, how do I achieve this kind of indexing?

Comment: Do a for loop twice? Edit: Ah, never mind, I didn't see the continued indices part of the question.

Comment: Use modulo arithmetic, if `i` is your index, use `S[i%len(S)]` (but pre-compute `len(S)` into a variable, don't compute it every time)

Comment: Ah I see, thanks. Do you know a way to solve this in `C` and `Java`?

Comment: @Abhishek the same principle applies, see for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8454228/how-can-i-get-the-nth-character-of-a-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `S[i%len(S)]` to reiterate the string with the continued indices

Answer (score 0):

Well, here is what you can do:

```
      string = "something"
      
      #iterate through string
      for element in range(len(string)):
        print(string[element])
```

You can do this how many ever times you want.